# nodejs restify with nginx reverse proxy could not get session works

Tags: node.js, session, nginx, express-session, restify

so a little background first: I use restify framework for my nodejs api server, and I use react for client to interact with the server. I setup both projects in one VPS with nginx reverse proxy to take care with two different domain name: `example_server.com`,`example_client.com` and both https enabled with letsEncrypted.

so when I visite `example_server.com`, my nginx take me to localhost:server_port and show the correct content, the client works the same way.

Here is my problem:

my react client connected to restify server could not get session work, the server not able to setup any session for the client. it maybe related to nginx reverse proxy problem, someone use express framework for server has the same issue, but got fixed using `app.set('trust proxy', 1)`. but in restify, there is no such option. I really don't want to change my code from restify to express, so What can I do?

my server nginx setup:

```
server {
    server_name server_example.com www.server_example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

my client nginx setup:

```
server {
    server_name client_example.com www.client_example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I use `express-session` for handling session in my restify server, in local development it works well, but in VPS server with nginx, it is not working. here is the code Snippet:

```
var constant = require('./config/constant.json');
var session = require('express-session');

var restify = require('restify');

var corsMiddleware = require("restify-cors-middleware"); 
const cors = corsMiddleware({  
  origins: constant.client_urls,
  credentials: true,
  allowHeaders: ["Authorization"],
  exposeHeaders: ["Authorization"]
});

var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.use(restify.plugins.jsonp());
server.pre(restify.plugins.pre.userAgentConnection());

server.pre(cors.preflight);  
server.use(cors.actual);


//server.set('trust proxy', 1);  restify didn't has such option, err: .set is not a function.
server.use(session({
  secret: constant.session_secret, 
  proxy: true,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 3600000, secure: true },
}))
```

any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out the problem is causing by the two different domains.

React client `www.myReactClient.com` is able to connect to Restify API server `www.myRestifyServer.com` with CORS enabled, then server will generate a session, keep it to itself while sent only session-id to client side with cookie.

the React client should carry that cookie and send session-id back to server whenever it makes request to, so that server will recognize this client.

However, due to using two different domains, the cookie was consider as 'third party cookie', and browser block that kind of cookie by default, so the cookie remains there but never got used, so the server won't receive the session-id.

so, Long story in short, after I change the browser setting to **NOT** block third party cookies, everything works as planned. Then I change my two different domains to one domains with one subdomains, `www.myReactClient.com` for hosting React Client, `api.myReactClient.com` for hosting Restify API server, the third party cookie issue be solved as well.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about this because I was requesting for a subdomain and now, I have copied the API service to the under subdomain's server. It is working.